# In bash how to print all sibling processes of current process

Tags: linux, bash, process, pid

I know the pid of my current process... I am trying to figure out the processes who have same ppid as the pid of current process

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ps` `--ppid` to select by parent PID, Using bash builtin variable `PPID`.

```
ps --ppid "$PPID"
```

Comment: In what version does `--ppid` work?  `ps -o ppid $PPID` should work in all versions.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Under Mint 19.1 (Ubuton) `ps --version`returns `ps from procps-ng 3.3.12`.